# Parse server return invalid session token for public records and only when calling functions

Tags: ios, session, parse-server

ok this is something that start to show a few weeks ago, I have a parse server running on an ubuntu machine with version 2.3.3, I have a bunch of cloud functions running, nothing fancy just querying some specific Class, all the data in that class is public and all work most of the time just fine. However from time to time, calling a cloud function start to return invalid sessions error 209, even with a user logged or not, super weird, but what is even strange is that when that happens no one else can run the function, and every user start to got the same error.

The only way I can make it work again is restarting the server, also only happens with cloud functions and from the ios app, I saying this cause we have some other part calling functions from php but it seems those are not starting the problem

```
2017-02-21T01:26:57.676Z - Failed running cloud function partnersv2 for user undefined with:
Input: {"k":"","searchType":"","category":"comida"}
Error: {"code":141,"message":{"code":209,"message":"invalid session token"}}
2017-02-21T01:26:57.669Z - invalid session token
2017-02-21T01:26:55.738Z - ParseError { code: 209, message: 'invalid session token' }
2017-02-21T01:26:55.737Z - Error generating response. ParseError {
code: 141,
message: ParseError { code: 209, message: 'invalid session token' } }
```

I have no idea why is this happening, also I don't think is related to the legacy session cause this server and the user are new, we start developing this a few months ago is not a ported app from the old service

One thing we are doing a lot is removing from the dashboard sessions at will, cause we are testing and developing, not sure if this could be a reason, but what about when the user is undefined, it shouldn't even try to use session I think, or maybe a user that was actually logged could be the culprit, setting the server to VERBOSE is not telling anything else as well, just the params and the call which it doesn't look weird to me, am looking for someone that maybe can put me in the right direction of maybe how the session work or something, thank you for any help

EDIT 1:
This is the cloud function that is trowing the error

```
Parse.Cloud.define('partnersv2', function (req, res) {
    var searchType = req.params.searchType,
            k = req.params.k,
            category = req.params.category,
            query;

    query = new Parse.Query('Partner');
    query.addDescending('is_open');
    query.equalTo('enabled', true);
    query.equalTo('category', category);
    query.select(['name', 'phone', 'delivery_eta', 'keys', 'price_range', 'is_new', 'cover', 'recommended', 'open_time', 'min_order', 'delivery_rank', 'logo', 'comingsoon', 'category', 'is_open']);
    if (searchType !== '' && searchType !== undefined && k !== '' && k !== undefined) {
        if (searchType === 'Tag') {
            query.equalTo('tags', k);
        } else {
            query.equalTo('name', k);
        }
    }
    query.limit(1000);
    query.find({
        success: function (results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                res.success(results);
            } else {
                res.error('404 not found');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            res.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

and this is a screenshot of the ACL col

[image: ACL public]

Comment: Can you show your Cloud Code function? I'd like to understand how you are using the user from the function. With the self hosted Parse, there is no longer a concept of "Current user" in Cloud Code so how you get the user and its session token has changed. This may help in identifying the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, am not using the user, the class data is public so I call the function w/o a user, but yes sometimes the user could be defined if is logged even though am not using the user for this calls, let me edit my questions with some actual code

Comment: did you ever figure this out ? I'm having the same problem now....

Comment: Yes, this help me a lot https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/2255, however and the end I went and upgrade de server version and the issue goes away, I'm using version 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Use Master Key

```
Parse.Cloud.define('partnersv2', function (req, res) {
//var token = req.user.getSessionToken() // getSession Token return r: (yourkey);
var searchType = req.params.searchType,
        k = req.params.k,
        category = req.params.category,
        query;

query = new Parse.Query('Partner');
query.addDescending('is_open');
query.equalTo('enabled', true);
query.equalTo('category', category);
query.select(['name', 'phone', 'delivery_eta', 'keys', 'price_range', 'is_new', 'cover', 'recommended', 'open_time', 'min_order', 'delivery_rank', 'logo', 'comingsoon', 'category', 'is_open']);
if (searchType !== '' && searchType !== undefined && k !== '' && k !== undefined) {
    if (searchType === 'Tag') {
        query.equalTo('tags', k);
    } else {
        query.equalTo('name', k);
    }
}
query.limit(1000);
query.find({
    useMasterKey: true,   // sessionToken: token
    success: function (results) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            res.success(results);
        } else {
            res.error('404 not found');
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        res.error(error);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is not working, I actually already tried that, and it shouldn't be necessary to do it in the first place because all the data is public, no idea what is causing this, I have other server for other product and is running without an issue for months